# VMware Fusion: how can I access an Apache server in my Ubuntu VM from my Mac Host?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vmware, vmware-fusion

I install apache2 in Ubuntu with `sudo apt install apache2 -y`, start it up with `sudo service apache2 start`, and can access it on the Ubuntu VM with the address `localhost`. I found that I can access the server from the host using the VM's IPv4 address found in Ubuntu Settings > Network > gear icon. Every time I boot up my Mac with the VM and the Apache server, I want to be able to access it from the host using the same address everytime, whether it's a static IP address, or somehow by entering localhost. I tried tutorials from [here](https://itsfoss.com/static-ip-ubuntu/) and [here](https://graspingtech.com/vmware-fusion-static-ip/) to set a static IP address, but they don't seem to work, and I don't know much about networking.

Comment: Best to set up the Guest machine with Bridged Networking so the guest gets the address from the router. Then it can have a static IP address.

Comment: I should have noted that Bridged Network is a VMware Fusion setting.

Comment: Can you give me specific steps, or do I just take an IP address after connecting to a Wi-Fi, then used that for as a Static IP? How would I make a static IP?

Comment: In your router, you need to identify the DHCP range. A common DHCP range is 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.149 or .199 . You need to log into your router and identify this. Say the above is correct:  Give your Guest machine (Guest Network Adapter) an address of (say) 192.168.1.20, subnet mask of 255.255.255.255, and gateway of 192.168.1.1.   Try this

Comment: I started but was unable to complete this tutorial: https://medium.com/upinatoms-com/sharing-a-network-between-your-vmware-fusion-linux-guest-and-your-mac-os-x-host-70d98271f142, but got a solution as a result of just making a new private network adapter, refer to my answer below

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

- Shut down the virtual machine
- on the menu bar go to Virtual Machine > Settings > Add Devices
- Create a new Network device, set configuration to "Private to my Mac" under Custom, and generate a MAC address for it.
- Start up Ubuntu and Apache2 server
  ** If you want to be sure, In the settings app, and under network there should be more than one connection. Click the gear icon for each connection until you find the one with a matching MAC address. Copy the IP address for it.
- Follow [this tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/static-ip-ubuntu/) to change the IP Address to a static one (in the netplan file, use the IP address copied in the step above). This will make the IP address stay the same.
- Entering the IP address on the VM host should take you to Apache's test page.